# vk-api python, photo access key. Как получить ключ доступа к фотографии, которая отправлена в лс боту ВКонтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать бота, который в лс будет получать картинку и ответ к ней, а в беседе будет ее отправлять и ждать ответа к картинке. вроде всё сделал, но останавливаюсь на проблеме с access key для фото, которое отправляет юзер боту в лс. Как его получить?